# pipleline script for build in android studio project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build, jenkins-pipeline

wondering if anyone here can help me with a script that i can run my android studio project from Jenkins?
this is the pipeline script that i currently have:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            steps {
                git url: 'https://github.com/AvielCo/ParkNBark'
            }
        }
        stage("Compile") {
            steps {
                sh "./gradlew compileJava"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> run my android studio project from Jenkins

You don't "run" your project in Jenkins. Jenkins is tool to build, test, and deploy your project.

Android projects are Gradle projects. So to build a debug APK, you would do:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            steps {
                git url: 'https://github.com/AvielCo/ParkNBark'
            }
        }
        stage("Build debug APK") {
            steps {
                sh "./gradlew assembleDebug"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with Android development. You can refer to the linked below guide for command line usages for Android.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline